# How to update/change values in a text file in python

Tags: python, replace, text-files, key-value

How can I change text file values/items using user input? For example, I will update the value of RECOVERED (COVID case) in my text file. I don't know where to start.

Here is the content of my text file

```
COUNTRY,CONFIRMED,ACTIVE,RECOVERED,SUSPECT,PROBABLE,DECEASED
COUNTRYA,4,2,2,2,0,0
COUNTRYB,2,0,2,0,0,0
COUNTRYC,2,0,0,3,0,2
COUNTRYD,2,1,1,3,0,0
```

Comment: How often does this need to be updated? Will it be updated from multiple threads/processes/applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to reliably make "in place" updates of a CSV file like you demonstrate in your post. Generally you would have to just overwrite the file.

However *in memory* it's very easy to modify tabular data. I recommend using the Pandas library for its DataFrame data structure.

For example, if you want to load the file, change the number of confirmed cases for Country D to 10, then re-save the file, your code would look something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col='COUNTRY')
data.at['COUNTRYD', 'CONFIRMED'] = 10
data.to_csv('data.csv')
```

If you want to have a more robust application, e.g. to handle concurrent/threaded updates or very frequent updates, you should use a different file format instead. I personally use SQLite databases for this purpose, with the [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) package in the standard library.

---

*Edit-*

If you can't use Pandas, you can read and write the data using the [csv package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) in the standard library. I recommend storing the data in a dict of dicts. Here's an example:

```py
import csv

def read_data(filename):
    data = {}
    with open('data.csv') as fp:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fp)  # auto-detects field names
        for row in reader:
            key = row['COUNTRY']
            value = {k: v for k, v in row.items() if k != 'COUNTRY'}
            data[key] = value
    return data

def write_data(data, filename, fieldnames):
    with open('data.csv', 'w') as fp:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        for key, value in data.items():
            row = {'COUNTRY': key, **value}
            row[''] = key
            writer.writerow(row)

data = read_data('data.csv')
data['COUNTRYD']['CONFIRMED'] = 10
fieldnames = list(next(data.values()).keys())  # get the field names from the first element in the dataset
write_data(data, 'data.csv', fieldnames)
```

Please carefully read the example. As always, **do not copy and paste code that you do not fully understand**.

Comment: Can I do this without using panda? I'm having a problem installing panda. Is there any other way? Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @benjarmintia I added a non-Pandas example. Read it carefully, do not copy and paste. I provide no warranty, it is not tested, and it might contain bugs.